# Saving duplicate instances of an entity in an array for a many-to-many relationship

Tags: typescript, database, postgresql, many-to-many, typeorm

I'm designing a database for a trading card game using Postgres and TypeORM (and GraphQL, though that is less relevant). Decks need to be able to save multiple instances of the same card within them, because decks are allowed to have up to 4 copies of a single card. When I save a deck into the database that contains an array of cards with duplicate entities, what actually gets saved is just the unique cards, without duplicates copies.
Is this a limitation/quirk with Postgres or TypeORM, or is this just a limitation on relational databases in general? If I'm simply unable to to save duplicates in a relation like this, what might be the best solution to saving the amount of each card that a deck has?

Here are simplified snippets of the relevant code:

```js
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Deck extends BaseEntity {
    // snip
    @Field(() => [Card])
    @ManyToMany(() => Card, { eager: true })
    @JoinTable()
    cards!: Card[];
    // snip
}
```

The previous is a uni-directional relation, and `Card` has no column relating to `Deck`.

```js
const deck = await Deck.create({
    // snip
    cards: cardsWithDuplicates,
    // snip
}).save();
```

The previous call to `Deck.create().save()` yields the following output in the console:

```sql
query: START TRANSACTION
-- snip
query: INSERT INTO "deck_cards_card"("deckId", "cardId") VALUES ($1, $2), ($3, $4), ($5, $6), ($7, $8) -- PARAMETERS: [16,259,16,260,16,261,16,262]
query: COMMIT
```

as you can see in the parameters, it's only inserting 1 of each unique `cardId` (259, 260, 261, 262), even though the array `cardsWithDuplicates` contains multiple instances of each card.

I've been unable to find any info online relating to my problem, though my lack of knowledge/experience with databases could mean that I simply don't know how to best phrase the question. Any suggestions/criticisms are welcome.